# Alternatives to Fuller’s (2009) Sampling Statistics

Tags: references, survey-sampling

I’m taking a self-study course in sampling statistics this semester and my professor chose Fuller’s (2009) Sampling Statistics for both the content and the homework questions.

However, I am really really struggling to understand the content under Fuller’s teaching method. There are many, many steps in Fuller’s work that are assumed to be understood; sadly, this causes me to spend 12+ hours per week trying to comprehend the background knowledge and failing. I really appreciate Fuller’s expertise but I would really appreciate a book that teaches topics a little more, as I want to be able to complete a homework question sometime soon.

Do you all have any recommendations for a rigorous sampling statistics textbook that generally does a good job of breaking down theorems? Since it is a self study course I would like to use these recommendations to propose a different text to my professor.

Comment: I would definitely vouch for the very classic __Sampling Techniques__ by _Cochran_. While the treatise is bit old and doesn't cover all the things that Fuller has, the treatise is worth to study for its clear and lucid exposition as well as systematic development of concepts.

Comment: Another favorite introductory text of mine would be __Sampling Theory and Methods__ by _Sampath_. This is a short book but not at the expense of detailed presentation.